# ErrorException in ModuleController.php line 1753:

Tags: php, laravel

Do you have any idea about this error:

> **ErrorException in ModuleController.php line 1753:**
>
> include(/home/tramersi/public_html/sistem/resources/views/sximo/module/template//config/route.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: means that the file is not found check your link  i see two `//` !!!

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that the file `/home/tramersi/public_html/sistem/resources/views/sximo/module/template//config/route.php` is not found on the system.

Several things are curious about your post:

- `sistem` appears to be a misspelling of `system`
- `template//config` might indicate a dynamically generated string that is missing a component

But the strangest part is at the end, `config/route.php` -- old versions of Laravel used to use a `routes.php` to define routes, but this hasn't been true for several versions. What version of Laravel are you using?

For further assistance, please paste a full stack trace (http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) as well as the source code of ModuleController.php line 1753 and relevant surroundings.

Comment: Line 1753 in ModuleController.php `include(base_path().'/resources/views/sximo/module/template/'.$row->module_type.'/config/route.php' );`

Comment: @Selim I assume that's your answer then -- `$row->module_type` is outputting an empty string, which leads to the file not found? I'd suggest `dump($row)` above this line to see what's going on.